# EF Setup database type of In-Memory database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, case-insensitive, in-memory-database

Is it possible to setup type of in-memory database by Entity Framework? I need this In-Memory database correctly to be as Oracle SQL.

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;
MyDbContext context = new(options);
```

Background: I'm using in-memory database in my unit tests. In real code I'm connecting to Oracle SQL and in one method I check content of string in database by Entity Framework by using function:

```
predicateBuilder.And(user => EF.Functions.Like(user.Name, "john"))
```

In my unit tests working method `Like` as case insensitive but in real code it's working as case sensitive. I found another question and solution for that and I know that this method `Like` works differently for SQL/SQLite, Oracle/Postgres..

I fixed this issue but for avoiding to have similar issues I'd like to setup in memory database be same type as my real database (for me Oracle SQL)

Comment: If you're going to use Oracle in production, nothing but Oracle should be used when testing.

Comment: Agree for regression testing but for unit tests will be overkill to connect to real database. I'm using in-memory only for unit tests or in past I was using mocking EF functions.

Comment: Never mind that the in-memory database is only meant for quick unit testing. Why do you want to test *Oracle syntax* with Entity Framework? EF isn't a database driver, it's job is to abstract the database entirely, giving the impression of working with application objects. If you use it to execute raw SQL, something is very wrong

Comment: The collation issue you talk about isn't even a product issue. You can specify case sensitive or insensitive collations in all databases. The default in Oracle is case-sensitive. The default in SQL Server is case-*in*sensitive

Comment: The [in-memory provider simply doesn't support case sensitivity](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6153), along with any other relational concept. It's just a wrapped `Dictionary<string,T>`. It's meant to mock the database in unit tests, not emulate it.  If you want to test case sensitivity use the SQLite provider in in-memory mode. If you want faithful replication of Oracle, use a test version of Oracle. Unit testing doesn't mean you shouldn't use a database when you need to test database behavior

Comment: I'm not using Oracle syntax in code. Or do I use it?

Comment: I just want to compare 2 strings by case insensitive and for only this scenario I don't want to change whole database settings

Comment: In past I mocked EF functions but I much more like using in memory database. It's much more easier and clear work in unit tests and also is very fast. But yes for this scenario, it'd work better.